# Connect AWS ApiGateway to Internal ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, aws-security-group, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to make one of the services (say an echo server for this example) that I have on my EKS cluster within my VPC available to external users. My approach to doing this is to first create an internal/private ALB that routes traffic to the service, and then have an ApiGateway HTTP API send external traffic to the ALB. Here are the steps that I have taken:

1. Create a security group that allows inbound traffic on port 80 from all ipv4 and ipv6.
2. From the ApiGateway page create a VPCLink. Select the private subnets associated with my ALB as well as the VPC of EKS cluster and ALB.
3. Create and ApiGateway HTTP API with the `$default` auto-deployable stage.
4. Create a route for `ANY /{proxy+}`. For the record I have also tried using the path `ANY /` but still get the same result.
5. For the path created in step 4 create an integration. The integration is set to use the VPCLink created in step 2. I also select my ALB and its listener for port 80.

However, when I follow the above sequence of steps and go to the address created by ApiGateway I get the following response: `{"message": "Not found"}`.

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the target group health check status of the ALB?

Comment: @gohm'c can you further explain what you mean here? I'm able to manually send successful request to the alb from an ec2 that is within my vpc. So I assume that the alb is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the API Gateway is deployed? The error message seems to indicate no routes are available.

If it is deployed, but something is wrong with your backend, the error is typically like so:

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Comment: It should be as the stage is set to auto deploy.

Comment: If the deployment failed, the auto-deploy will not work though. You can check if any error message by navigating to the stages menu in API GW.

Comment: I repeated the process. Before attaching the integration it showed that there was an error with the deployment. However, once I added the integration to the `ANY /{proxy+}` route that all went away. But I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: Ok. That's strange, I followed your steps and the API is working fine. I also deliberately misconfigured the connection at different points. No routes matching in API GW yields the `Not found` that you also got. Then if API GW cannot find the ALB yields `Internal Server Error`, ALB cannot find the backend yields `503 Temporarily not available`, and backend cannot find the page yields app-specific error, like `404 resource not found`. So I strongly suspect the problem is about API GW cannot match the route.